# Permissions problems when using Microsoft graph explorer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have a personal MS teams Home account. I am trying to use the Microsoft graph API to send messages to my teams user.

I log with my teams user in the microsoft explorer site https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer and I can query my own user id using this request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

And here ends the fun.

If I try to see my chats like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{my-id}/chats
```

I get this error:
*Forbidden - 403 - 670ms. Either the signed-in user does not have sufficient privileges, or you need to consent to one of the permissions on the Modify permissions tab*

If I go to to the modify permissions tab I see this:

*Permissions for the query are missing on this tab. Open the permissions panel to see the full list of Microsoft Graph permissions and select the permission(s) you want and consent to them from there.*

And if I click on the "consent to permissions" link. I get a list of permissions with blue buttons that say "consent". I clicked the consent buttons for the channels permissions and for the teams permissions, but it did nothing. If I re-run the request I still see the error about permissions. Also when I logged out of the graph explorer and logged in again, and I wen back to the "consent to permissions" it looked like the permissions I had consented before had been reset.

So how can I configure the permissions to be able to create teams, channels, send messages to chats, etc using the Microsoft graph explorer?

Comment: For delegated code flows, Microsoft Graph evaluates whether the request is allowed based on the permissions granted to the app and the permissions that the signed-in user has. Generally, this error indicates that the user is not privileged enough to perform the request, or the user is not licensed for the data being accessed. Only users with the required permissions or licenses can make the request successfully.

Please have look into this doc for user consent-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/permissions-consent-overview

Comment: Yes it looks like my user lacks privileges. But how can I get those? I see no place in the microsoft teams app to give my user more privileges. As I said is a home account, I basically registered, and download the app, so I do not know how can I say ey I should be able to send messsages to myself (or see my chats) to test the graph API.

Comment: As per the document, it is not supported to personal account-[![enter image description here][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUQQE.png
Ref doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Comment: Hi @Art, has the above information solved your issue.

Comment: Hi MehTab, yes, it looks like since I have a personal account I am limited in which I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Sign up for a free MS developer program and you can use the api above, so you won't be limited.

For limited features, external items connectors are limited in developer program.